# Is [AWorrkbookName] new or old syntax for VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm maintaining a piece of code and came across this in a VBA function:

```
isIn("Fred", [PeopleList])
```

Where PeopleList is a workbook named range. I've never noticed that syntax before and just wondered is it something I've missed or is it new? Should I pass in the range into the function or is this okay usage?

Comment: someone else's (deleted) answer pointed to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221553%28v=office.11%29.aspx which I found helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [PeopleList] syntax is shorthand for Application.Evaluate("PeopleList") and it will try to evaluate PeopleList as a formula or named range and return the result as a variant containing an array. This usage is OK and has been available in VBA since Excel version 5.

Comment: Thx. I didn't know that and I've been using excel in anger since 1997. The only thing I don't like about that syntax is it is effective a workbook defined global variable that I must be aware of if I'm move sheets and / or code around.

Comment: Don't see why moving sheets or code is a problem - the defined name will move with the data. Some people prefer to use the alternate EVALUATE(string) syntax on the grounds that its more maintainable to hold a constant string variable somewhere.

Comment: I should have been explicit that I meant moving code and sheets inter-workbook. Many of my sheets and nearly all my code get reused.